# Does a "melee spell attack" use my spellcasting ability, or my Strength?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, attack, melee-combat

The spell "Flame Blade" makes a fire sword that you can perform a melee spell attack with. As a druid with higher Wisdom, I would rather have it be based on that than my Strength, but I'm not sure if I would use my Wisdom or Strength, considering it is a '**melee** *spell* attack.

Would I use my Wisdom for the melee spell attack from Flame Blade, or my Strength? Cause I feel like if it's based on Strength, there's no real need for the spell for a druid.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange! Can you tag your question with the edition of the game you are using?

Answer (score 21):

### It uses your spellcasting modifier and proficiency

The pertinent part of the [*flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-blade) spell description says:

> You can use your action to make a **melee spell attack** with the fiery blade. On a hit, the target takes 3d6 fire damage.

Melee spell attacks are also covered in PHB pg. 206, in the ["Attack Rolls" section of the Spellcasting chapter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls) (emphasis mine):

> Some spells require the caster to make an attack roll to determine whether the spell effect hits the intended target. **Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus.**

Answer (score 16):

## Spell attacks use your spellcasting ability

The *Player’s Handbook* says about [spell attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls):

> Some spells require the caster to make an attack roll to determine whether the spell effect hits the intended target. Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus.

So in the case of Flame Blade, you would use your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus.

## ...But you should read the wording carefully

There are spells that use a melee attack that are not “melee spell attacks”. For instance, [Booming Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) and [Green-Flame Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) (SCAG, p. 142-143) are not dependent on a melee *spell* attack. Instead you must make an attack with a melee weapon. They say:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must **make a melee attack with a weapon** against one creature within the spell’s range, otherwise the spell fails.

This would be different than the spell in question because, you are making an **attack with a melee weapon,** so you would add your modifier that applies to that weapon (Strength or Dexterity) and your proficiency (if you are proficient with that weapon).

Comment: @V2Blast thank you for that edit. It flows much better, and is the exact spirit of the answer that I wanted to give!

Comment: Glad to help! :)